# How come I am able to use sudo without being in sudoers?

Tags: sudo

I am new to Linux and I am using Centos7 from AWS and I am slightly confused. To my understanding, in order to use sudo, you need to be in sudoers and by default, the root user and group wheel are in sudoers. I am currently the centos user and I can use sudo, but I can't understand why. I don't believe I am in the group wheel.
[image: My sudoer file]

[image: And using cat /etc/group, I don't see centos in the group wheel]

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/108618).

Comment: Also, post (text) example of how you're successfully using `sudo` ?

Comment: Also check `/etc/sudoers.d` for any included files.

Comment: I've no idea what those images show, other than it seems to be screenshots of text. Please replace them with the actual test so that the information is readable

Answer (score 3):

In cloud environments, many distributions (including CentOS 7) use [cloud-init](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to configure the system when it first boots.

If we look at `/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg` on the CentOS 7 cloud image, we find:

```
system_info:
  default_user:
    name: centos
    lock_passwd: true
    gecos: Cloud User
    groups: [wheel, adm, systemd-journal]
    sudo: ["ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL"]
    shell: /bin/bash
  distro: rhel
  paths:
    cloud_dir: /var/lib/cloud
    templates_dir: /etc/cloud/templates
  ssh_svcname: sshd
```

This says, "create a user named `centos` and apply the `sudo` configuration `ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL` to that user. This causes `cloud-init` to create the file `/etc/sudoers.d/90-cloud-init-users` with the content:

```
# Created by cloud-init v. 18.2 on Mon, 08 Aug 2022 22:07:23 +0000

# User rules for centos
centos ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

And that is why the `centos` user has `sudo` access.